# JAXB generic list serialisation using Map

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-rs, jaxb2

I've got a class that wraps a generic list. When I put a Map in that generic wrapped list, the JAXB output is not what I expect. Items are shown, but their contents isn't.

To elaborate:
A simplified version of my class:

```
@XmlRootElement @XmlSeeAlso({HashMap.class, ArrayList.class, Dummy.class})
public static class TargetClass<T> {
  public List<T> wrapped = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

When the wrapped list contains a Map, the result is not what I'd expect. Using:

```
@GET @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public TargetClass<Map<String, String>> thisIsWhatIWant() {
  Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put("hello", "world");
  TargetClass<Map<String, String>> result = new TargetClass<>();
  result.wrapped.add(map);
  result.wrapped.add(map);
  return result;
}
```

I get:

```
<targetClass>
  <wrapped xsi:type="hashMap"/>
  <wrapped xsi:type="hashMap"/>
</targetClass>
```

But I was hoping for

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<targetClass>
  <wrapped>
    <entry>
      <key>hello</key>
      <value>world</value>
    </entry>
  </wrapped>
  <wrapped>
    <entry>
      <key>hello</key>
      <value>world</value>
    </entry>
  </wrapped>
</targetClass>
```

There is a lot of good JAXB answers on here (thanks @blaise-doughan and others), but as far as I could find, not on this one.

Other things I tried:
Lists and Maps are serialized like I expect if I use them directly

```
@GET @Path("baseTest") @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public BaseTest thisWorksAsExpected() {
  BaseTest baseTest = new BaseTest();
  baseTest.list.add("item");
  baseTest.list.add("item");
  baseTest.map.put("hello", "world");
  baseTest.map.put("foo", "bar");
  return baseTest;
}
```

output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<baseTest>
  <list>item</list>
  <list>item</list>
  <map>
    <entry>
      <key>hello</key>
      <value>world</value>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <key>foo</key>
      <value>bar</value>
    </entry>
  </map>
</baseTest>
```

TargetClass works as expected when I drop an XMLRootElement in there:

```
@XmlRootElement
public static class Dummy {
  public String a = "a";
  public String b = "b";
}

@GET @Path("other") @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public TargetClass<Dummy> other() {
  TargetClass<Dummy> result = new TargetClass<>();
  result.wrapped.add(new Dummy());
  result.wrapped.add(new Dummy());
  return result;
}
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<targetClass>
  <wrapped xsi:type="dummy">
    <a>a</a>
    <b>b</b>
  </wrapped>
  <wrapped xsi:type="dummy">
    <a>a</a>
    <b>b</b>
  </wrapped>
</targetClass>
```

Any clue?

Groeten,

Friso

Comment: Oh, bonus question: I can serialize a HashMap as <wrapped><hello>world</hello></wrapped> using an XmlJavaAdapter, but how do I use a specific adapter on a generic class? I.e. TargetClass<Map<?,?>> should use the adapter, but TargetClass<String> shouldn't